# var_export() and static class properties

Tags: php

I played around with [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-export.php) and I'm wondering why static class properties not getting exported by var_export().

```
class TestStatic {
    public static $FOO_BAR = 'foobar';
}

$testStatic = new TestStatic();

var_export($testStatic);
```

Results in

```
TestStatic::__set_state(array(
))
```

Is there any reason why static properties will not be exported by var_export()?

I know that `static` means `it never changes`. So that static properties will not be exported by var_dumo() make sense. **But** it's possible in PHP to change a value of a static property afterwards so a value of a static property could propably change during runtime:

```
$testStatic = new TestStatic();
$textStatic::$FOO_BAR = 'new value';
```

Comment: See my edit above you can change the static value during runtime. So if I put a static value in `__set_state` its propably not the value the instance of the class have had before I exported it.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of programming and classes `static` usually doesnt mean that it doesnt change, it means that it's not tied to instances of the class. For example in Java `finally` means it doesnt change

Then it would be wierd if they were contained in an instances of the class.

So even if PHP allows you access $v with $inst::$v, it still accesses the class' variable and not the objects variable.

```
class A
{
    static $v;
}

A::$v = '1';
echo A::$v;        /* outputs '1' */

$inst = new A();
echo $inst::$v;    /* outputs '1' (this should never be the way to access static vars)*/
$inst::$v = '2';

echo $inst::$v;    /* outputs '2' (this should never be the way to access static vars)*/
echo A::$v;        /* outputs '2' */
```

If you really want the static properties you write your own:

```
class A
{
    static $v = 'VV';
    public $b = 'BB';
}

function export_all($o)
{
    return array_merge(get_object_vars($o), get_class_vars(get_class($o)));
}

$c = new A();
var_dump(export_all($c));

outputs:
array(1) { ["b"]=> string(2) "BB" } array(2) { ["b"]=> string(2) "BB" ["v"]=> string(2) "VV" }
```

If you want the private variables aswell you have to call it from within the class, you'll have to add something like this to the class:

```
public function export_it() {
    return array_merge(get_object_vars($this), get_class_vars(get_class($this)));
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know but PHP breaks this rule. Cause you can do: `$testStatic = new TestStatic(); $testStatic::$FOO_BAR = 'new value';` I would never do that because it's bad coding but you can. And from there on static properties are bound to the class instance cause `new value` is instance specific.

Comment: No, it's still not tied to the class, that probably just PHP guessing what you want to do. Check my sample code

Comment: Okay I see the point but why PHP does allow to overwrite a static property outside the class? That results in very confusing code doesn't it? (as your example above shows it)

Comment: Indeed it's wierd that you're allowed to do it, but my guess is that if you check in your error log for PHP (and turns on all warning) you probably see an error that you access static properties wrong..

Comment: No it unfortunately doesn't I set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and no warning occures. Anyway: Is there a extended var_export() version which respects the runtime class changes (like static property changes)?

Comment: I dont think there is a builtin but you could use  get_class_vars() and extract the class-variables and build your own method that does var_export first and then add whetever get_class_vars() returns for that object

Comment: Well your example above is okay but does not export the object as valid PHP code. So it's not an extended version of `var_export()` but thx anyway :-).

Answer (score 1):

1. A [static property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) is not a [class constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php):

   > Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
   > without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as
   > static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (though a
   > static method can).
2. Since [var_export()](https://www.php.net/var_export) is designed to export a variable, it can only export a class *instance*. As such, the static property simply does not belong there. Neither `print_r()` nor `var_dump()` or even `serialize()` show static properties for the same reason.